# VB.NET Add data to textbox in external form

Tags: vb.net

Hello again StackOverflow community.
 I need to add text to an externally generated form into TextBox.

My Code (For generating new form):

```
Public Sub NewPage()
        Dim newtab As New CenterForm1
        newtab.MdiParent = Me
        newtab.Show(DockPanel1)
        newtab.ComID.Text = newtab.codeblock.Name
        newtab.codeblock.Name = +count
        newtab.Name = +count
        count += 1
    End Sub
```

My Code (for insert text to TextBox):

```
Dim GetActive As GetActiveWindow
Dim codeblock As New TextBox
GetActive.codeblock.Text = "TESTIIIING"
```

Code for "GetActivateWindow" class

```
Imports WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking

Public Class GetActiveWindow
    Public Property codeblock As TextBox

    Public Function GetActive()
        'Verify if forms that dock in main window are already open

        For Each form As DockContent In Form1.DockPanel1.Contents
            If form.DockHandler.Pane.ActiveContent.DockHandler.Form.Name.ToString() = form.Name.ToString() Then
                Dim formName As String = form.Name.ToString()
                Return formName
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in simple words, are you trying to dynamically create a new form and a textbox and add some text to it?

Comment: No, I want Form1 to get the text into the Form2 TextBox that is created Dynamically. Form1-->Click button to Get form2 name and insert the text from Form1 to a Form2(Created dynamically) a TextBox

Comment: oh okay, i gotchu

Comment: form2 name? or the text? i mean the title